# Adding select to model removes .count functionality (rails)

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, join

When creating a join table as follows

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :time_pledges, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :volunteers, through: :time_pledges

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :time_pledges, foreign_key: "volunteer_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :volunteering, through: :time_pledges, source: :project

class TimePledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :project
```

I am able to do the following `@project.volunteers.count` and get an answer for how many users are volunteering for a specific project at that time. However when I update the project model to be able to access the hours_pledged attribute of the join table model (`time_pledges`) as follows:

```
  has_many :volunteers, -> { select('users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged as hours_pledged')}, through: :time_pledges
```

I am no longer able to access `@project.volunteers.count.` The error I get is as follows

```
 P1.volunteers
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged as hours_pledged FROM "users" INNER JOIN "time_pledges" ON "users"."id" = "time_pledges"."volunteer_id" WHERE "time_pledges"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 300]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1, email: "durham@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$4fyCd4GGtwZ0NRzrJuPDd.KWAhXWWumJ1LqtqZOSYWQ...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-03-06 08:59:06", updated_at: "2015-03-06 08:59:06">]>
>> P1.volunteers.count
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged as hours_pl...
                                                         ^
: SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged as hours_pledged) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "time_pledges" ON "users"."id" = "time_pledges"."volunteer_id" WHERE "time_pledges"."project_id" = $1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged as hours_pl...
                                                         ^
: SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged as hours_pledged) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "time_pledges" ON "users"."id" = "time_pledges"."volunteer_id" WHERE "time_pledges"."project_id" = $1
```

Also after I try to do a `@project.volunteers.count` I am no longer able to access any of my Users again (until I restart a console session). For example if I do something like `U5=User.find_by(id:5)` after a `@project.volunteers.count` I get the following message:

```
User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
D

**EDIT 1**

Schema

```
  create_table "time_pledges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "volunteer_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "hours_pledged"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "time_pledges", ["project_id"], name: "index_time_pledges_on_project_id", using: :btree
  add_index "time_pledges", ["volunteer_id", "project_id"], name: "index_time_pledges_on_volunteer_id_and_project_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "time_pledges", ["volunteer_id"], name: "index_time_pledges_on_volunteer_id", using: :btree
```

Using times_pledges instead of time_pledges

```
  >> P1=Project.first Project Load (1.7ms) SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1 => #<Project id: 301, title: "awe", user_id: 101, created_at: "2015-03-06 15:19:17", updated_at: "2015-03-06 15:19:17", required_hours: 7> >> P1.volunteers NameError: uninitialized constant Project::TimesPledge
```

Using

```
has_many :volunteers, -> { select('users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledged')}, through: :time_pledges
```

gives

```
    >> P1.volunteers    
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledged FROM "users" INNER JOIN "time_pledges" ON "users"."id" = "time_pledges"."volunteer_id" WHERE "time_pledges"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 301]]
    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
    >> P1.volunteers.count
    PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "hours_pledged"
    LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledg...
                                                             ^
    : SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledged) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "time_pledges" ON "users"."id" = "time_pledges"."volunteer_id" WHERE "time_pledges"."project_id" = $1
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "hours_pledged"
    LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledg...
                                                             ^
    : SELECT COUNT(users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledged) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "time_pledges" ON "users"."id" = "time_pledges"."volunteer_id" WHERE "time_pledges"."project_id" = $1
```

Comment: I am running on the same **PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR**, executing a `destroy` after `.find()`. So, if somebody has any idea, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

In using Postgresql I don't use AS unless it's for a select statement that I am joining to i.e.

```
SELECT parts.*, alias_skus
  FROM parts
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT part_id, array_agg(sku) alias_skus
       FROM part_aliases GROUP BY part_id)
  AS sub1
  ON parts.id = sub1.part_id;
```

For column aliases, just leave out the 'AS'. You can see here I'm using the alias `alias_skus`.

thus:

```
  has_many :volunteers, -> { select('users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged hours_pledged')}, through: :time_pledges
```

Comment: So if I understand what you saying it would become:

  has_many :volunteers, -> { select('users.*, time_pledges.hours_pledged  hours_pledged')}, through: :time_pledges

I tried this and the errors and behaviour that I am getting still persist

Comment: Yes. Also it's unclear what your schema is. What are the columns in `TimePledge`? Is this a true join table? Does it have it's own `id` column? or are `user_id` and `project_id` the only columns? If it's a true join table Rails usually expects it to be called `times_pledges`, i.e. a plural of both tables names being joined.

Comment: Did this work? I don't have a rails 4 app that is similar enough to check.

Comment: I actually just tested it with a Rails 4 app I have. I added it as a scope to a has_many through: relationship and it works. I did not receive any errors. You say you are still getting the errors, but I assume you are not still getting the "AS" error, since you removed the "AS". Did you remember to restart the web server or rails console before trying it? The model loads on startup.